# Easy way to combine lightbox-functionality with Expresso

Tags: channel, image, expresso, entry

Has anyone come up with an easy way for non-html-savvy users to put lightbox-style images into an Expresso (CKEditor) field.

Meaning, link a thumbnail with a bigger version of an image and fire some lightbox-script on click.

Having the user supply both the thumbnail and the big picture would be OK but the process shouldn't be too complicated and must not involve editing the HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

About the most "user-friendly" way I've found (for generic CKeditor) is as follows:

1. Use "Browse Server" to insert thumbnail then link the large scale image with "browse server"
2. Under
   "advanced" tab in link menu type in a specific class name (like "lightbox")
   into the stylesheet classes.
3. Use javascript to come back and hook onto all the .lightbox classes. You can also use the Relationship field in the advanced tab to create galleries (at least with [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).)

It's still a couple steps, but it doesn't involve seeing any HTML :)

Note: I'm using the WYGWAM flavor of CKeditor so I'm not sure if the expresso build has the exact same interface, but the principle should still apply.